# Windows hybrid app fails connecting to MobileFirst Server

Tags: android, windows, windows-phone-8, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app

I am using IBM MobileFirst 7.1 for creating a hybrid app.

The Android and iOS version of the app works fine in the production environment. 
However, the error message "Failed connecting to MobileFirst Server" is displayed on running the app on Windows phone.

The 'wlServerProtocol', 'wlServerHost', 'wlServerPort','wlServerContext', 'wlAppId' entries in wlclient.properties file are same for android, ios and windows app. 
Also on checking with the network team, the connection requests from the app are reaching the load balancer as per the configuration in wlclient.properties file. However, as the app is unable to connect to the MF Server, no entries are visible in the MF Server logs.

While testing the app in the development environment on a windows device, it worked fine and was able to connect to the MF Server.

So my queries are:

1)Is there some extra configuration to be done for the windows phone platform for connecting the app to MF server in the production environment 
or are there some other steps specific to the Windows phone platform ?

2)Is it possible to view MF Server logs in eclipse while running the app on Windows emulator with Visual Studio.

Comment: There are no production specific configurations for Windows Phone . Can you confirm if you are trying out the Windows Phone Silverlight or Windows 8.1 Universal? Has the network team analyzed the load balancer settings to see why it is not forwarding the request to MFP server, when coming from Windows?

Comment: Hello Vivin, I had created environment for Windows Phone Silverlight. I haven't discussed with the network team about analyzing the load balancer settings. However, as per my discussion with the team, there is no os platform specific settings done for connecting to the MF Server. They were of the opinion that as the android and ios apps have connected to the server successfully, the windows app should be doing the same ideally.

Comment: Hello Steven,  Since the request for Windows Phone is reaching the loadbalancer but does not register at MFP server, I was just wondering if there is a network angle to the problem. If loadbalancer is indeed forwarding the request to MFP server, we could try two things:
a) Enable trace on the MFP server and check what is happening
b) Network trace at the MFP server - wireshark/tcpdump, to see if the request is reaching the MFP server

Comment: Thanks Vivin, i'll do that and update about any leads.

Comment: @StevenJ, any updates?